# Making a graph of the robot links of Xacro file

Tags: ros, urdf, xacro, ros-indigo, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know if there is a way to make a graph like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=graphiz.png) from a Xacro file. It is explained that it is possible from URDF with the URDF_to_graphiz. However, it doesn't work with Xacro.

I tried converting it to a URDF file, but that left me with nothing but transmissions from ROS control. Is there any way that is it possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238873/making-a-graph-of-the-robot-links-of-xacro-file/) by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It is explained that it is possible from URDF with the URDF_to_graphiz. However, it doesn't work with Xacro.

Well, yes. Xacro is not urdf. They somewhat relate to each other as classes and objects do in say C++: you have to create instances of your classes to get an object.

> I tried converting it to a URDF file, but that left me with nothing but transmissions from ROS control

this suggests you tried to convert the wrong `.xacro` file. You have to convert a 'top-level' xacro (ie: the one instantiating all the macros), or it won't work.

If you can give a little more detail (which `.xacro` are you trying to convert, how did you do it, command line(s) etc), we might be able to help you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on 2016-07-06**:
Ok, it's clear where I screwed up. I didn't convert the top-level xacro file. Instead I used the lower level one.